# Need to move complete unix disk from old HP to new box

Tags: mount

I have an old HP 715/80 that is running some really old software that we need to continue using. The software is no longer available. I am wanting to somehow clone or move the data to a new Unix/Linux machine. The only thing the HP has is a tape drive so I am lost on how to proceed. Any insight would be great.

Comment: Do you know what kind of tape-drive this is? And what kind of interface (SCSI)? I have successfully transfered material from HP/SGI/DEC using DLT, DAT and ExaByte to Linux machines which support a variety of SCSI controllers. Simply used  `tar` of `cpio` to write and read the tapes.

Comment: What OS is running there and what kind of processor platform is this?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three options for getting the material from the HP 9000 workstation

1. writing the material to tape and reading the tapes on a compatible device connected to the new box
2. ethernet using the Intel Apricot based 10 Mbit Ethernet interface
3. serial communication (as available on the 715/80)

The above is probably also the order of speed for transfer (although it depends on the tape interface in use).

The 715/80 has a SCSI interface, and if you can bring the old machine down after writing the material to the tapes, you can connect the drive to a scsi interface that you plug-in your new (Linux) box. I have 3 different SCSI controllers and all are supported by Linux without any effort, but of course you should select one that is supported.

If you cannot disconnect the drive, and are not willing to invest in a drive just for transfer, then you should try and transfer the material via the ethernet. 10Mbit is slow for today’s standard (I have gigabit ethernet at home), but your HP workstation probably  has a low capacity drive compared to today’s standards as well. What I have not been able to find out is if it is 10Base-2 or 10Base-T (the former using coaxial cable and you don't see that kind of ethernet boards to often in Linux machines (but my first one had one and it did work). If you already have a network connection, that should not be an issue, but if the machine is stand-alone you would have to figure that out.

The final option is connecting the HP with another computer using the serial cable (most new motherboards still have a serial connector, but it is has become seldom available on the back of the system by default like it used to be). With that you get transfer-speeds of up to 100kbit/s, that might be enough.
As software the venerable `uucp` and transfer programs like kermit, sz (IIRC).

If you have a compiler on the HP machine, you might be able to use any of the simpler serial protocols (after compiling the software), otherwise (in case of no compiler) you probably have to go with what is available on the HP, but `uucp` should be there and can be used from Linux as well.